# iCloud Photo Library uploads from Windows: albums and mov

Tags: icloud, photos, video, quicktime

I am trying to migrate from Flickr to iCloud Photos, and having some trouble. I am currently using an iCloud account on a Windows 10 machine.

1. Albums: It seems to be possible to upload albums from Photos.app on a Mac, but not on Win - only choice is upload and then organise. Am I wrong?
2. Is there a supported file spec for iCloud anywhere? The one I've seen mentions support for MOV files, but with no codec specifics. I am trying to upload .mov files from an old Lumix.

A "normal" video .mov uploads fine. The issue is with the other mov type, which might be Motion JPEGs (these are essentially photos with an .amr sound recording packaged in a .mov). iCloud won't accept those even after conversion into an mp4. Is this because of the very low (sub-500kbitsec) bit rate?

Converting to MP4 with a custom VBR and stitching multiple of those files seems to have worked. Although iCloud for Windows still gives an "Unsupported file error", it is uploaded. This leaves question one.

Comment: Why would you use an Apple service designed around Apple products on a Windows machine?  Why not go with OneDrive or something similar?  Instead of going to Photos, why not imgur, 500px, Behance, etc?  All are good cloud based photography services.

Comment: @Allan good point. Thing is, iOS devices would be primarily used going forward, so iCloud would be most convenient, I would like to avoid splitting the library and paying for 2/3/4 services

Comment: My primary platform is Apple and I don't use iCloud.  It's not a requirement